# div dentro de header no aparece arriba a la derecha

Tags: html, css, html5

El div que muestra "Usuario : Anonimo" no aparece donde quiero, no consigo que el div *(dentro de un header)* con `id="divLogin"` aparezca **arriba a la derecha** en Chrome, sin embargo en Edge si.

En Chrome como se puede observar aparece bajo el `nav` a pesar de que le especifico `display: inline-block`. Es como si no pillara bien los estilos.

El código HTML de la cabecera lo incluyo como cabecera común así:

```
<%@include file="/parciales/header.jsp"%>
```

En otros archivos jsp, pero no creo que este sea mi problema sino *mas bien un problema de css*.

Mis archivos son:

- *HTML* : header.jsp
- *CSS*: cssLayout.css

Este es mi código:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

**header {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

header>#divLogin {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 17px;
}

** header>.menu>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header>.menu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  heght: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

header>.menu>ul>li>a {
  color: #727272;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header>.menu>ul>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #A83939;
  color: white;
}

.divAlertaCorrecto {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.divAlertaError {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Registrar datos en el sistema</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ver los datos registrados</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="divLogin">
    <b>Usuario: </b>
    <%=request.getSession().getAttribute("correoElectronico")!=null ? 
         request.getSession().getAttribute("correoElectronico") : "Anónimo"%>--
  </div>
</header>
```

*En Chrome se ve mal:*

[image: Chrome Mal]

*Pero en Edge se ve bien:*

[image: Edge Bien]

Comment: Que lenguaje utilizas para obtener el `correoElectonico` o `Anonimo`?

Comment: es java metido en un archivo .jsp mediante <% %>.

Comment: Si ejecutas tu codigo y presionas "Pagina completa" si aparece arriba y a la derecha.

Comment: Tampoco me funciona ponerlo a "Pantalla completa" con f11.Se queda en el mismo sitio

Comment: Me refiero aqui, cuando presionas el boton "Ejecutar", del lado derecho veras un link que dice "Pagina completa", si presionas ese link se ve correcto.  Por lo menos yo lo veo bien.

Comment: Ah,no sabia bien a que te referías.Pero bueno,me debe funcionar en Chrome y nada

Comment: A mi si me funciona.

Comment: Prueba con display flex y cambia el flex-direction o usa el -webkit-

Answer (score -1):

intenta darle esta propiedad en tu css ahh y quitale la posision absolute

```
#divLogin {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: No me ha funcionado incluirlo float:right al final de header>#divLogin..muchas gracias

Comment: intenta relative en vez de absolute

Comment: tampoco me funciona cambiar absolute por relative,no se si será cuestion de como se organicen los elementos en un header para Chrome